# iNotify multiple read

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

I use the following code to monitor a file using I notify. I first poll and then read if there is a change to prevent blocking:

```
int settingsCheck(int &length, int &i, char * buffer, int &fd, string setRead[])
{
    int f_change = 0;

    struct pollfd pfd = { fd, POLLIN, 0 };
    /* Poll with a timeout of 100ms */
    int ret = poll(&pfd, 1, 100);
    /* Check to see the result of the poll */
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Poll failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else if (ret == 0) {
        /* Timeout with no events -> move on */
    }
    else {
        /* Process the new event */
        struct inotify_event event;
        length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);
        printf("read\n");

        while (i < length)
        {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
            if (event->len)
            {
                if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY && event->name == "setitngs.txt")
                {
                    printf("The file %s was modified.\n", event->name);
                    //f_change = 1;
                }
                else if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                {
                    printf("Not settings\n");
                }
            }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
        readSettings(setRead);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I modify the text file being monitored (which is modified by a php script), my program reads the file multiple times (2-4), sometimes only reading the correct data on the final read.

Does anyone know why this happens / how to fix it?

PS: I am correct in saying that if I call the readSettings() function inside the following if:

```
if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY && event->name == "setitngs.txt")
```

then readSettings() should be called only once when "settings.txt" is monitored?

Comment: event->name == "setitngs.txt" is incorrect - event->name is char*. Also, what do you mean by 'correct data'? You could get a lot of events by single write - opend, modification, closed, etc.

Comment: That still does not solve the multiple read problem. Whether I have the name part or not it reads multiple times. Also, by correct data I mean correct contents of the text file.

Comment: No, i meant this condition will just never be true. As for multiple events - show your inotify_add_watch calls.

Comment: wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/var/www/settings.txt", IN_CREATE | IN_MODIFY | IN_DELETE);

Comment: IN_MODIFY occurs on each write - so you could get a lot of them. Try using IN_CLOSE_WRITE - event occurs once file that was opened for writing is closed